# RDMA CM for Windows

Tags: windows, infiniband, rdma

Does anyone know if there is a Windows equivalent for the RDMA Communication Manager found on Linux (http://linux.die.net/man/7/rdma_cm -- librdmacm), and also ib verbs (libibverbs)?

Both these libraries are available when installing drivers for Infiniband Hardware on Linux distributions.....but what about Windows?

I've read about Windows Network Direct, but since i'm already familiar with the above mentioned Linux libs, I would like to use (if possible) their equivalents on Windows.

I have established data transfer (RDMA writes) between Linux nodes, but now I have to RDMA data from a Windows node to a Linux node, but at the moment I'm not sure which route to follow....

How do I determine whether Windows Network Direct will be compatible with IB verbs/RDMA CM?

I was under the impression that the verbs spec would be implemented on both platforms...!

Kind regards

Answer (score 1):

librdmacm and libibverbs should be provided by your OpenFabrics Enterprise Distribution (OFED).  There's an open source OFED for Windows provided by OFA: https://www.openfabrics.org/index.php/-download-windows-installer-.html.